# save value of type object to MongoDB using TypeORM

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I want to store key value pairs to a MongoDB using TypeORM. My backend API is made with NestJs (not sure if this is important). The key is of type `string` and the value is of type `object` because I want to store *anything* to this object.

This is my TypeORM database configuration

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mongodb',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  database: 'nest',
  entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity.{ts,js}`],
  synchronize: true,
}),
```

My mapping entity does not auto generate the key because I want to set it on my own

```
@Entity()
export class Mapping extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  key: string;

  @Column()
  value: object;
}
```

When I want to save a new mapping to the database I run this logic (it doesn't matter where)

```
  const newMapping: Mapping = new Mapping();
  newMapping.key = 'foobar';
  newMapping.value = { foo: 'bar' };
  await newMapping.save();
```

I'm getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'propertyName' of undefined

when executing the `save` function of the database entity. It seems that I can't store the value of type `object` to the database. Any solutions for this?

Comment: What if you rename your id column from `key` to `id`?

Comment: Hey, I updated my code and use `id` instead of `key` now. Unfortunately the error remains the same

Comment: Can you change decorator from `PrimaryColumn` to `ObjectIdColumn`?

Answer (score 0):

When working with TypeORM + Mongo, your entities must have their ID columns decorated with the `ObjectIdColumn` decorator, e.g.

import {Entity, ObjectID, ObjectIdColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

```js
@Entity()
export class Mapping {

    @ObjectIdColumn()
    key: ObjectID;

    @Column()
    value: ;
}
```

> Defining entities and columns is almost the same as in relational databases, the main difference is that you must use `@ObjectIdColumn` instead of `@PrimaryColumn` or `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`.

[TypeORM Mongo Docs](https://typeorm.io/#/mongodb)

Comment: thanks. The problem with that is that I want to assign the `key` manually with a string.  Assigning a `key` to the field is not possible anymore due to `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ObjectID'` any ideas?

Comment: 2. I think `@ObjectIdColumn({ generated: false })` should disable the auto generation. But have to fix the first problem before testing :)

Comment: Hm I currently solved it with this solution `@Entity()
export class Mapping extends BaseEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  id: ObjectID;

  @Column()
  key: string;

  @Column()
  value: object;
}` but I'm not sure if this is a good one ...

Comment: @hrp8sfH4xQ4 I think you can also add your column as `@ObjectIdColumn() key: string` or something like that, TOGETHER with the `@ObjectIdColumn() id: ObjectID` field. If you do, however, you will always have to specify `key` value when querying and saving.

Comment: would you mind showing a simple snippet for that entity then? you want me to have two unique identifiers?

Comment: @hrp8sfH4xQ4 I am referring to [this issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2530#issuecomment-507054366) on github. I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try NestJS support for MongoDB.

> TypeORM has basic MongoDB support. Most of TypeORM functionality is RDBMS-specific, this page contains all MongoDB-specific functionality documentation. [typeorm docs.](https://typeorm.io/#/mongodb)

Instead try to use NestJS approach. They built a module for MongoDB, it's a bit more code to write but is much more into mongo than Typeorm. It uses npm mongoose package. I currently use this and it works very good and it's not that hard to implement.

Here are their docs on NestJS / MongoDB. [MongoDB | NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: hm yes, thanks. I just tried both of them and think typeorm fits better to me... I have to design one entity and with mongoose I have to design an interface, a schema and so on ...

Comment: I did that too, but then I needed pagination and other mongoose plugins, which I couldn't use with typeorm so easy, so I made this trade and used mongoose.. Typeorm says that in the future they will try to make their package more mongo friendly. Anyway, everything that works for you! Good luck!